# Errors in Access 2003 front end after switching DSN to sqlncli10

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access-2003, dsn

I have an Access 2003 front end linked (DSN) to a SQL 2008 back end. I had originally developed it using the older sqlsvr32 DSN driver, but were having performance issues. A new DSN was created to use the sqlncli10 (Server 2008r2 version) driver and the tables relinked. This increased performance, but now causes what looks like timeout errors at unpredicable intervals in the front end with everything from ADO recordset queries to simple dropdown box populations. The only thing which has changed is the driver, and I can't determine the cause of these timeouts. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DSN was created using the OBDC manager (odbcad32.exe) using the Sql Server Native Client 10.0 (2009.100.1600.01). Tables were dropped and re-linked from the database (SQL Server 2008). This did not resolve the issue. Custom functions were re-written to use ADO, and tables were converted to a DSN-less connection with the same driver. Neither had an apparent effect on the issue. The issue was resolved after targeting different servers for testing to see if the server was the problem. Any server with 2008 R2 did not show any symptoms on this issue. The issue was resolved by uninstalling all SQL server instances, installing 2008 R2, and restoring the databases. I'm not sure of the exact cause, but this seems to fix the issue.